How to Simulate ECU Initialization Sequences for ELM327 Communication?
I have created an OBD simulator in Python that emulates an ECU (Engine Control Unit) of a car. However, when I attempt to read data using an ELM327, I receive the message "unable to connect". According to the ELM327 datasheet, the ELM327 waits for certain initialization sequences from the ECU to establish a connection:

The ELM327 looks for specific bytes (called keywords) to be sent to it during the ISO 9141-2 and ISO 14230-4 initiation sequences. If the bytes are not found, the initiation is said to have failed (you might see ‘UNABLE TO CONNECT’ or perhaps ‘BUS INIT: ...ERROR’). This might occur if you are trying to connect to a non-OBD compliant ECU, or perhaps to an older one.
If you wish to experiment with non-standard systems, you may have to tell the ELM327 to perform the initiation sequence, but ignore the contents of the bytes that are sent and received. To do this, send:
AT KW0
After turning keyword checking off, the ELM327 will still require the two keyword bytes in the response, but will not look at the actual values of the bytes. It will also send an acknowledgement to the ECU, and will wait for the final response from it (but will not stop and report an error if none is received). This may allow you to make a connection in an otherwise ‘impossible’ situation. Normal behaviour can be returned with AT KW1, which is the default setting.

The OBD simulator is located on a Raspberry Pi 4. I have already tried to send the AT KW0 command via Bluetooth serial to deactivate these bytes, but the problem persists. Performing a candump on the Raspberry, I get this output when I try to request a PID reading (e.g., I send 0100):
  can0       648   [2]  49 49
  can0       5D7   [4]  remote request
  can0       5D7   [4]  remote request
  can0       5D7   [4]  remote request

My questions:

What are these ECU initialization sequences?
What do these sequences consist of?
How can I simulate these sequences to successfully interface with the ELM327?

**This is my code: **
class obd2_simulator: 
    def __init__(self):
        #costrutture della funzione
        self.interface = "socketcan"
        self.channel = "can0"
        self.bus = can.Bus(interface = self.interface, channel = self.channel)
        self.pids = {
            #pids.....
        }
        def get_supported_pid1(self):
            return [0x06, 0x41, 0x00, 0x18, 0x7f, 0xFF, 0xE3, 0x00]

        def get_supported_pid2(self):#pid 20
            return [0x06, 0x41, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
        
        #other function for pid.....
        def requesting(self, message):
        if message.arbitration_id == 0x7DF: #si tratta di una richiesta
            print("test1")
            mode = message.data[1]
            pid = message.data[2]
            if mode == 0x01 and pid in self.pids: #modalità dati in tempo reale
                print("test2")
                data = self.pids[pid]() #chiamo la funzione corrispondente
                response = can.Message(
                    arbitration_id = 0x7EF,
                    data = data,
                    is_extended_id = False
                )
                try:
                    self.bus.send(response)
                    print("risposta inviata correttamente")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"errore: {e}")
            
            else:
                print("NO DATA")

def get_message(self):
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    msg = self.bus.recv() #controllo se ci sono messaggi
                    print("messaggio ricevuto correttamente")
                    if msg is not None:
                        self.requesting(msg)#se non è vuoto lo passo alla funzione che gestisce le richieste
                except Exception as e: #se c'è un eccezzione esco dal ciclo e chiudo il bus. 
                    print("error in get_message()")
                    print(e)
                    break
        finally:
            self.bus.shutdown()

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
